# Editar registro no banco de dados

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando editar um Form usando `fill()->save()` mas ao invés de fazer update o Laravel 5 tenta fazer `insert` e dá erro dizendo que o registro já existe na tabela.

```
$input = $request->all();
$record->fill($input)->save();
```

Estou usando `rules: class MeuFormRequest extends Request`

```
'nome' => 'required|unique:empresa,nome' . ($id ? ",$id" : '')
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que possa estar errado?

Comment: Dá primeira um find pra procurar os dados com aqueles valores, ai você joga os parâmetros como o novo valor e depois da um save. Ex: $user = User::find(1); $user->email = 'john@foo.com'; $user->save();.
Ou você pode fazer direto User::where('votes', '>', 100)->update(['status' => 2]);

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Coloque um trecho maior de código. Para que o *Eloquent* reconheça como update, você precisa dar um **GET** do objeto antes, do contrário será considerado como um novo registro, porque não possui nenhum `ID` relacionado,

**Ex**:

```
$model = Model::find(1);
$model->fill($input);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Valeu!